# Ошибка "Module did not self-register" при попытке загрузить bcrypt в дочернем процессе

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

Тестовый проект накидал: https://github.com/Suvitruf/bcrypt-child-process-crash-proof

```
const {Worker, isMainThread} = require('worker_threads');

if(isMainThread)
    console.log("I'm ok, because I'm alpha main");
else
    console.log("I'm sad, because I can't load bcrypt");

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

function runTestWorker(workerData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const worker = new Worker('./index.js', workerData);

        worker.on('message', resolve);
        worker.on('error', reject);
        worker.on('exit', (code) => {
            if (code !== 0)
                reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
        })
    })
}

async function run() {
    const result = await runTestWorker('I will crash your app  (｡•́︿•̀｡)');
    console.log(result);
}

if(isMainThread)
    run().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

При попытке подгрузить bcrypt в дочернем процессе падает с ошибкой:

```
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:779:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (O:\Texts\Sources\my\bcrypt-child-process-crash-proof\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
```

### Инфо:

- Node v11.10.0
- bcrypt v3.0.4

Что делать?